# How to open the gallery when the user click on the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Always when i open my page, the gallery open every time automatically.  but i only want that opens if the user click on the button. how can i fixed this problem?

```
<a onClick="$('.fixed-bar').toggle('slow');"

<div class="container demo-3">
                 <div class="main">
                   <div class="fixed-bar">

                    <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/3.jpg" alt="image03" /></a></li>

<script type="text/javascript">

            $( '#carousel' ).elastislide( {
                minItems : 2
            } );

        </script>
```

Comment: Always avoid the use of inline JS, it's ugly and hard-maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume fixed-bar div needs to be hidden on page load

make `<div class="fixed-bar" style="display:none">`

Instead of `<a onClick="$('.fixed-bar').toggle('slow');">` stuff use

```
<a id="gallery-toggle" href="">Toggle Gallary</a>
```

and inside `<script></script>`

write this code

```
$('#gallery-toggle').click(function()
{
    $('.fixed-bar').toggle('slow');
});
```

Much better approach.. :-)

OR in your code, just add `display:none` in style attribute.. That will solve the issue.

Let me know how that works,

Regards,

Rahul

Comment: i add the display:none.. and it works.. but the only problem is that when i click to open the gallery, they show no images. only the background

Comment: Were the images displaying before?